# Where exactly do the tunnels and vineways in Maze of the Blue Medusa connect?

Tags: published-adventures, osr

In Maze of the Blue Medusa the description of room 186 indicates that there is a tunnel to room 50. In room 50 there is no mention of such a tunnel. Is the tunnel there and how easy is it to find?

The vineway with entrances in rooms 43, 45, 198, 200 and maybe 47 is similar; room 47 does not mention it, though rooms 43 and 45 do. Rooms 198 and 200 do not mention the possibility of accessing room 47. How do the vineways connect, and do they connect to 47 at all?

An answer presumably relies on author commentary or a more careful reading of the book.

Comment: I feel the questions are sufficiently similar to be in one question; if not, splitting is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

The thumbnail and diagram on page 131 include the tunnel, and the thumbnail and diagram on page 45 do not include it.

> That and given the density of the growth in 50,

it seems clear that without extraordinary measures the intent is that players will not find the tunnel. So much so that there's not even a mention of a possibility in 50's description.

---

Likewise, the thumbnail and diagram on pages 39 and 137 make it clear how rooms 43, 45, and 47 are connected to rooms 198 and 200.

Comment: First one is a possible interpretation, though suspicious, given how large a part of usual OSR playstyle player freedom is. The characters might very well have a magical means of detecting secret doors, or an elf who always gets to check for them, etc.

Comment: @Thanuir I'd call those extraordinary measures. There's also a lot going on in room 50, so the players may not even choose/be able to engage those abilities.